# UIImageView does not appear in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview

I have a need to display three images per row in a tableview. I have created a custom tableviewcell that has three imageviews in it. The tableView in its cellForRowAtIndexPath: method gives the names of the images to the cell and the cell is expected to load them side by side in a row. But the images are not appearing in the tableView. I am not sure why it isnt working. Please help!

Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    customCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[customCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSString *imageForCell = [arrayImages objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*3)];
    cell.firstImageName = imageForCell;
    imageForCell = [arrayImages objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*3)+1];
    cell.secondImageName = imageForCell;
    cell.thirdImageName = [arrayImages objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*3)+2];
    return cell;
}
```

The customCell.m:

```
#import "customCell.h"

@implementation customCell
@synthesize firstImageView, secondImageView,thirdImageView, firstImageName, secondImageName, thirdImageName;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        //Make the Rects for the images
       CGRect rectForFirstImage = CGRectMake(10, 0, 90, 140);
        CGRect rectForSecondImage = CGRectMake(110, 0, 90, 140);
        CGRect rectForThirdImage = CGRectMake(210, 0, 90, 140);

        //create the Image views with the Rects
        firstImageView.frame = rectForFirstImage;
        secondImageView.frame = rectForSecondImage;
        thirdImageView.frame = rectForThirdImage;


        //set the images
        [firstImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:firstImageName]];//tried setting the image this way also
      //  firstImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:firstImageName];
        secondImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:secondImageName];
        thirdImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:thirdImageName];

        // set the content mode for the image views to fit in the images
        firstImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        secondImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    thirdImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

}
return self;
}

-(void) layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.opaque = NO;

    [self.contentView addSubview:firstImageView];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.secondImageView];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.thirdImageView];
}

@end
```

Comment: Found out why this code was not working. The images within the imageviews are to be set in the TableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath method. So I create and assign the images to the imageViews within the cellForRowAtIndexPath and send it to the cell. This works to the extent that it displays one image per cell. I am not sure why it isn't displaying the other images.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code for your task.I used SDWebimage for assigning image.You can use without SDWebimage also.Its working try this

if(indexPath.section==0)
    {

```
    if ([self.array count]>0)
    {
        if ([self.array count]>indexPath.row*3)
        {
            LooksObject *looksObjectRef1 = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*3];

            [cell.firstImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:looksObjectRef1.looksThumbImage] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image.png"]];



        }

        if ([self.array count]>(indexPath.row*3)+1)
        {
            LooksObject *looksObjectRef2 = [self.array objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*3)+1];

            [cell.secondImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:looksObjectRef2.looksThumbImage] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];

        }

        if ([self.array count]>(indexPath.row*3)+2)
        {
            LooksObject *looksObjectRef3 = [self.array objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*3)+2];

            [cell.thirdImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:looksObjectRef3.looksThumbImage] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];

        }

    }
}
```